# MSAL not allowed to install cocoa pods for target 9.0

Tags: ios, swift, azure-ad-msal

I am implementing log in with Microsoft in my swift project and using MSAL for this. https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc

This is my pod file.

```
target 'TestMSL' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

# Pods for TestMSL
  pod 'MSAL', :git => 'https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc', :tag => '0.1.3'

end
```

For pod install it gives me error like **CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "MSAL"**
[image]

Here strange is if i change my deployment target to 10 then pod installation works well.
Please help me how can i solve this. I want minimum deployment target 9.0.

Comment: use carthage instead of cocoapod i was also facing same issue with cocoapods

Comment: Yes but please take a look on README file. They provide instruction for cocoapods and its working well with sample project. So i am unable to identify where is the issue in set up.

Comment: I have the same issue and no matter how I change the deployment target inside XCode, still it gives the same error. Until I saw the green text on the screen shot above. I actually have to open the Podfile and change this line: platform :ios, '9.3' Originally it was 9.0 and I read in the MSAL documentation that it requires 9.3

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer from the microsoft authority on github

**Current iOS deployment target supported by MSAL is 9.3. They haven't tested MSAL on iOS 9.0, so it's not officially supported.**

**Also, we'll be shortly dropping iOS 9.3 support around the time when iOS 12 gets released.**

[Original Answer](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-objc/issues/292#issuecomment-406353816)